# LWJGL - Problem with capturing keyboard events

Tags: java, lwjgl

i have a one problem with LWJGL Keyboard module. I need to detect pressed keys, and i know how to do it. But, when i press key, LWJGL returns me 2-3 events. So for example, if i press ***'A'***, LWJGL calls 3 events, and i getting ***'AAA'***. How do i fix it? Here is my code:

```
Keyboard.enableRepeatEvents(true);
if(Keyboard.getEventKeyState()){
        if(Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_BACK){
            set.setValText(""); // Clean text
        }else{
            set.setValText(set.getFieldText() + Keyboard.getEventCharacter()); // Add event symbol to my string
        }
    }

    Keyboard.next();
```

Comment: You could try using key release events only, or have a boolean which stores whether the key was already pressed and can be discarded. I don't know much about LWJGM or if there is any way to fix it internally.

Answer (score 1):

I want to make a comment but not enough reputation to do it so I post as an answer

Basically when a key pressed, there is more than 1 event fired, for example: key down, key up, key pressed, key released,...

[Arcording to document from LWJGM](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__input.html) (I'm not familiar with it, just googled for a while), there is at least 2 events when pressing a key:

```
#define GLFW_RELEASE   0
```

The key or mouse button was released.

```
#define GLFW_PRESS   1
```

The key or mouse button was pressed.

```
#define GLFW_REPEAT   2
```

The key was held down until it repeated.